# ngrepeat not working when passing JSON array into angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass an array of JSON objects into my directive and then repeat them back using ngrepeat, however it is not working and it is not clear why.

I have created a jsfiddle which shows the problem that I am experiencing.

https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15997/

Is anybody able to tell me what I am doing wrong? I don't understand why it won't let me do this.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('dir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            items: '@'
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><h6>descriptions below</h6><div ngrepeat="x in items"><p>{{x.desc}}</p></div></div>',
        link :function(scope){
            console.log(scope.items);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have a typo in your template. Its `ng-repeat` and not `ngrepeat` - notice the "-".

Secondly, you have defined your scope with the `@` property. This causes the data that you pass to be in the form of a string and not the original type.

You have two choices here. Either parse the string to its original type using `JSON.parse()` or use the `=` property type which passes the data to the scope in its original format.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ozaqqc0/)

Comment: Thank you the ngrepeat was a bug that cropped up in my POC rewrite thank you very much changing the @ which I thought only meant read only to an = was the answer.